# How to make an editable event.keyCode

Tags: javascript, keycode, dom-events

```
function keydown(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 65) { //key A
        thing1();
        setTimeout(thing1, speed);
        setTimeout(thing2, speed*2);
        setTimeout(thing2, speed*2);
        setTimeout(thing2, speed*2);
    }
```

Would anybody know how to make the event.keyCode editable? Like instead of saying let's say 65 you can make it editable with a

```
<div id="s-keyn-split" class="setting-row">Split<span class="setting-option">
                    <div id="keybind-split" class="keybind-setting transitioning clickable">Space</div></span></div>
```

kind of thing? How could I make the code above select the keyCode when you set it to lets say S?

I'd want it to be something like this:

[image]

but it edits the keyCode value when selected and any key is pressed, not putting the letter but the keyCode number instead.

EDIT:
It's something about coding html as an add-on to the page
I'm making macros for the game, but if I'll release to public I need to make it easy to use
In other words, I need help with `event.keyCode`
I have a code that says:

```
if (event.keyCode == keycode number) {
Then the code of things to do when the key is pressed
}
```

So I was wondering if there's a way to make the `event.keyCode == (here)` editable as a var or such.
Basically making a clickable button that when it's pressed down you can type any key and it edits the keyCode as the number of the keyCode
and it sets it as the macro for the actions.
I know it's possible in some way because the site itself has macros that you can edit like that,
but with my tampermonkey script I cannot link the two with as much knowledge as I have in HTML and JS.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot change the keyCode. 
Here are a list of all the values based on the Unicode https://keycode.info/ based on the Unicode character code of the key that triggered the onkeypress event, onkeydown or onkeyup event. You could convert the values using a HashMap or write a decorator to wrap event.keyCode so it uses keyCode but it returns some other value that can fit your needs better. Let me know if I understood your problem and if this helps to solve the issue.

Comment: I know how to do it in my script but I was just trying to make an add-on to the page to edit them from the page instead of having to manually go into the code to edit the keycode

Comment: @acarlstein Edited post, might be more understandable

Comment: @WilliamBrand - check out my answer, it should help get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

@WilliamBrand, let me see if I understand. You are making a game and you wish to give your users the ability to set which key should be map to which action.

In short, no you cannot affect the values that the browser returns via event.keyCode.
You can create some adapter or decorator to wrap it around but you will only complicate your life. However, you can implement a map of actions that will hold the value of the key you can to assign to such action.

For example, map the letter A to Left action, D to Right action and so for. If this is the case, then perhaps you should consider to implement a map. So, it would be something like this:

```
if (event.keyCode == keyMap[LEFT]){
...
}
```

Now, you are in charge to decide that keyMap[LEFT] will hold as a value. 
You can write the code to say:

```
var userInputKey = ...;
...
    action = LEFT;
...
keyMap[action] = userInputKey;
```

So now, you can provide your user a way to reassign keys to a determine action.

Let me know if I understood correctly and if this idea can help you to create the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you want to be able have a key mapping that can be altered in a custom manner, so like when a game allows you to set the keys to move up, down, left, right etc.

You will need a routine that shows some sort of UI, waits for (or gets) a key press and stores the result somewhere to use later in your code.
I would use `event.key` as that gives you the actual key character pressed. If you don't want to use that, then consider `KeyboardEvent.code` for the code but be aware it has limitations (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code).

I have whipped up a quick example of what you could do - it's a bit hacky and probably not the most elegant way of doing things (e.g. hidden field to get key stroke =O), so use it as a starting point - you will need to modularise it and construct a way of passing the new settings to where they are needed:

```js
$("#readkeypress").on('keyup', function(e) {
  var keyset = e.key.replace(' ', 'Space');
  var setting = $("#setting").val();
  $("#setkey" + setting + "code").html(keyset);
  $("#theModal").modal('hide')
});

$('#theModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var theSetting = $(e.relatedTarget).attr("data-setting");
  $("#setting").val(theSetting);
  $(".modal-title").html("Press the key to set " + theSetting);
})

$('#theModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#readkeypress').focus();
})
```

```css
#customkeymappings {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #414141;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#customkeymappings div {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#customkeymappings label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
}

.keybtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  width: 60px;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #666666;
}

.maskedinput {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  border: 0;
}

.modal-header {
  border: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h4>
  Custom Key Mapping:
</h4>

<form id="customkeymappings">
  <div>
    <label>Left: </label><button type="button" class="keybtn" id="setkeyleftcode" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#theModal" data-setting="left">not set</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Right: </label><button type="button" class="keybtn" id="setkeyrightcode" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#theModal" data-setting="right">not set</button>
  </div>
</form>

<div class="modal fade" id="theModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="theModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header text-center">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Press the key to set</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <input id="readkeypress" class="maskedinput" value="" />
      <input id="setting" type="hidden" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would probably work if I could get the innerhtml or something from the element I add to the page, I forgot to mention this but it's an add-on to a page, not an actual site... Could I add this to the site somewhere and get the value when registered and update it every so many seconds in this way ```if (event.keyCode == document.querySelector('#thing').innerHTML)```? Like, make a loop for checking the innerhtml to use as the keycode?

Comment: @WilliamBrand - so you could use local browser storage to store/retrieve all the key mappings - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#Example - if I have time I'll integrate this into my answer.